# Windows Phone 8.1 listview bound textbox - how to setfocus and bring up the keypad?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have been struggling to accomplish it. It was easy in the older versions like Windows Mobile 6.5.

When a barcode is scanned, it should add it if not already in the list and set the focus to the bound textbox.

Barcode scanning and adding the scanned item to the listview works fine. **Setting the focus to the bound textbox and bring up the keypad is the one that doesn't work.**

In the FocusItem() below I'm able to get the reference to the exact box but it just won't setfocus and bring up the keypad even when it hits this line:

```
textbox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

Also, the AllChildren() I added below, it is unacceptably slow.

I am desperately looking for a way to accomplish this.

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="1,0,1,0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          SelectionMode="Multiple"
          DataContextChanged="listView_DataContextChanged"
          Holding="listView_Holding"
          Loaded="listView_Loaded"
          SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged"
          >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding BackGround}" Tag="{Binding RowNumber}">
                <Grid x:Name="row">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="270"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbQuantity" 
                           Margin="0,0,10,2"
                           Width="80"
                           Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                           FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"
                           BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           InputScope="NumberFullWidth"
                           Tag="{Binding RowNumber}"
                                 Loaded="tbQuantity_Loaded"
                           TextChanged="tbQuantity_TextChanged"
                           GotFocus="tbQuantity_GotFocus"
                           LostFocus="tbQuantity_LostFocus"
                           RequestedTheme="Light"
                           >
                            <!--<TextBox.Header>Quantity</TextBox.Header>-->
                        </TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void Barcode_ScanCompleted(object sender, Barcode.BarcodeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    SoundMediaElement.Play();
    AddItemByBarcode(e.Data);
}

private async Task<bool> AddItemByBarcode(string barcode)
{
            DataRow lastDataRowUpdated = OriginalSource.AddOrUpdate(barcode);
            await FocusItem(row: lastDataRowUpdated);
}


private async Task FocusItem(DataRow row)
{
        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataRow item in listView.Items)
        {
            if (item.Barcode == row.Barcode)
            {
                break;
            }
            index += 1;
        }

        listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.Items[index]);
            List<Control> controls = AllChildren(((Grid)((Border)((DataTemplate)listView.ItemTemplate).LoadContent()).Child));
            if (controls.Count>0)
            {
                if (controls[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    TextBox textbox = controls[0] as TextBox;
                    textbox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
                    //await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() => textbox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard));
                    //textbox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                }
            }
}

public List<Control> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var _List = new List<Control>();
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (_Child is Control)
            _List.Add(_Child as Control);
        _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_Child));
    }
    return _List;
}
```

Comment: It seems when we set the `TextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard)`, the TextBox will get foucus and the keyboard will show. Does the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event in TextBox be fired?

Comment: Instead of Getallchildren method you can get ListViewItem at index `i` using `listview.ContainerFromIndex(index)` and search for textbox inside that listviewitem using `VisualTreeHelper` methods. Ii might speed up the excecution

Comment: I tried different ways to narrow it down, but listview.ContainerFromIndex(index) always returned null, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just try ListView.updatelayout() before fetching item

Comment: That method isn't available, not sure why.